# React Router not rendering component even when URL changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios

I am using JWT token for authentication in reactJS with Django as the backend. When the refresh token expires, Axios is used as the interceptor and it changes the URL of the page to `/account/login`. However, the react-router does not render the login page.

Here is the code for my interceptor:
axios.js file

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();

axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
   return response
}, function (error) {
   const originalRequest = error.config;

      if (error.response.status === 401 && originalRequest.url.includes('/api/token/refresh/')) {
          console.log('101')
          history.replace('/account/login/')
          store.dispatch(actionCreator.setAuthFalse());
           return Promise.reject(error);
       }
```

Here is the code for my Route:

In App.js

```
<Suspense fallback={<Loader/>}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Fragment>
          <Navbar/>
          <Switch>
<Route exact path='/service/' component={AllServices}/>
<Route exact path='/article/' component={Article}/>
<Route exact path='/account/login/' component={LoginPage} />
         </Switch>
        </Fragment>
      </BrowserRouter>
     </Suspense>
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    accessToken: state.accessToken,
    refreshToken: state.refreshToken,
    expiresIn: state.expiresIn,
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return{
    auth_user_after_refresh: (refreshToken) => dispatch(authActions.getAnotherAccessToken(refreshToken)),
    logout: () => dispatch(authActions.logoutUser())
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

How do I make sure that the component renders when the URL changes?

Comment: We need to see the file where the `<Route />` and `<Loader />` live.

Comment: I have provide app.js file where all <Route/> components are present.